# get value inside <b> tag using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the value inside a  tag using scrapy. 
When I inspect the element, it shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WHSH.png)

So, I'm trying to get just the number without the m2 (in this case, just the 65 value)

I'm using this code

`item['supTotal'] = response.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/article/div/section[1]/ul/li[1]/b").extract_first()`

And i get in the csv column

```
<b>65m2</b>
```

How can i get just the 65? without the b tag and the m2 unit

Comment: Please do not post code as image. Always post code included as text in a `code` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
item['supTotal'] = response.xpath("substring-before(/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/article/div/section[1]/ul/li[1]/b/text(),'m')").get()
```

The result shoud be `65`.